# EF: Where are automated migrations details stored?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I got back to this project after half of a year and got a strange problem. I started on new environment so there is no database there. All should be restored from migrations. I have a bunch of coded migrations but it turns out that some (probably just one) was automatic. Despite this back then I added it also to coded migration and now during database restoring I get an error `Column names in each table must be unique`. My migration for this table is:

```
public partial class AddedUserEntity : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UniqueId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    UserName = c.String(),
                    Password = c.String(),
                    IsAdmin = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Deleted = c.Boolean(nullable:false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Users");
    }
}
```

My `User` class is:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

The column which causes problem is `Deleted`. If I comment out the line setting `Deleted` then whole database is restored correctly and the interesting part is that **deleted column is added to table**. 
The `TimeStamp` property is added by another code migration later and it works without problem.

So my question is how EF knows that it should add this column? If it takes it just from Entity class, then why only this one property causes the problem?